# Ruby on rails error when running rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

Um quite new to rails and um getting an error when run the command
    rails s
it says 
    Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
    Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
when I run bundle install nothing happened

my gem list has rake 0.9.2.2
what can go wrong?
my ruby version is 1.9.3
Thank you in advance

Comment: You might have a newer version of rake installed, that's why bundler complains. What happens when you run `bundle exec rails s`?

Comment: Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems. has happened :(

Comment: Try this one -> sudo apt-get install rake. May it will help you.

Comment: Kalanamith : Did you get any success ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove all the versions of Rake ==> gem uninstall rake
2. Remove your `gemfile.lock` => rm Gemfile.lock
3. Remove gem 'rake' on your `gemfile`
4. Run `bundle install`
5. Install Rake manually : `gem install rake --version=10.0.4`

Answer (score 1):

When you use command `gem list`, you will get a list of gem installed on your machine.

> For example : rake (10.0.4, 10.0.3, 0.9.2.2)

Just see the console which gem is compatible with your application. It is already mentioned in the error log message.

Use

> gem uninstall rake

Keep the suitable one and remove the version who is creating trouble. And then run `rails s` or `bundle exec rails s`

Answer (score 0):

Try using rvm and go back to ruby 1.8.7 instead of 1.9.2. This fixed it for me. Don't forget to install rails again (sudo gem install rails while already on 1.8.7) if you have only installed rails for 1.9.3.]

Comment: in the requirements it says to install 1.9.3

Comment: will suggest try doing that. Please Uninstall the previous versions and try running bundle install. Check your RVM as well