# You have already activated rake 10.0.4, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

What I have in my Gemfile

gem 'rake', '10.0.3' #first line in gemfile

Deleted Gemfile.lock

ran Bundle update

Ran bundle update rake

ran assets:precompile

I get the following message:

```
You have already activated rake 10.0.4, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.0.3.
```

Bundle show output:

Gems included by the bundle:

```
....
* rake (10.0.3)
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error message (the procedure I followed is a summary of advice on Stackoverflow)?

Comment: See my answer. If you use bundle exec, Will take Only the Gems which are listed in your Gemfile.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16838116/1297435

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **bundle exec** infront of your command

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

This will solve your issue.

```
I always recommend to use "bundle exec" before any such kind of commands.
```

Comment: My IDE (RubyMine) was part of the problem. When I was trying to precompile from the IDE, I was getting the error, When I did it from the command line, it worked fine. The same goes for rake route